# Searching efficiently with keywords

Tags: sql, postgresql, search

I'm working with a big table (millions of rows) on a postgresql database, each row has a `name` column and i would like to perform a search on that column.

For instance, if i'm searching for the movie Django Unchained, i would like the query to return the movie whether i search for Django or for Unchained (or Dj or Uncha), just like the IMDB search engine.

I've looked up full text search but i believe it is more intended for long text, my `name` column will never be more than 4-5 words.

I've thought about having a table keywords with a many to many relationship, but i'm not sure that's the best way to do it.

What would be the most efficient way to query my database ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My guess is that for what you want to do, full text search is the best solution.  (Documented [here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/textsearch.html).)

It does allow you to search for any complete words.  It allows you to search for prefixes on words (such as  "Dja").  Plus, you can add synonyms as necessary.  It doesn't allow for wildcards at the beginning of a word, so "Jango" would need to be handled with a synonym.

If this doesn't meet your needs and you need the capabilities of `like`, I would suggest the following.  Put the title into a separate table that basically has two columns:  an id and the title.  The goal is to make the scanning of the table as fast as possible, which in turn means getting the titles to fit in the smallest space possible.

There is an alternative solution, which is n-gram searching.  I'm not sure if Postgres supports it natively, but [here](http://wm.ite.pl/articles/sql-ngram-index.html) is an interesting article on the subject that include Postgres code for implementing it.

Comment: Full text search seems to be indeed the best solution, my requests are a lot faster now. They are still too long though but i believe i can find optimizations to do by myself. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The standard way to search for a sub-string anywhere in a larger string is using the `LIKE` operator:

```
SELECT *
FROM mytable
WHERE name LIKE '%Unchai%';
```

However, in case you have millions of rows it will be slow because there are no significant efficiencies to be had from indexes.

You might want to dabble with multiple strategies, such as first retrieving records where the value for `name` starts with the search string (which can benefit from an index on the `name` column - `LIKE 'Unchai%';`) and then adding middle-of-the-string hits after a second non-indexed pass. Humans tend to be significantly slower than computers on interpreting strings, so the user may not suffer.

Comment: I'm not sure i understood correctly the last part, but i'd say it would work only if the user has the first word. If the user just enter "Unchain" the search will be very long because not indexed. Maybe Django unchained is not the best example since people will probably type "django" first but with "the usual suspects" you can't expect people to type "the" first.

Answer (score 0):

This question is very much related to the autocomplete in forms. You will find several threads for that.

Basically, you will need a special kind of index, a space partitioning tree. There is an extension called SP-GiST for Postgres which supports such index structures. You will find a bunch of useful stuff if you google for that.